# kdb+/q optimize union function

Tags: kdb

To give you a bit of background. I have a process which does this large complex calculation which takes a while to complete. It runs on a timer. After some investigation I realise that what is causing the slowness isn't the actual calculation but the internal q function, union.

I am trying to union two simple tables, table A and table B. A is approximately 5m rows and B is 500. Both tables have only two columns. First column is a symbol. Table A is actually a compound primary key of a table. (Also, how do you copy directly from the console?)

```
n:5000000
big:([]n?`4;n?100)
small:([]500?`4;500?100)
\ts big union small
```

I tried keying both columns and upserting, join and then distinct, "big, small where not small in big" but nothing seems to work :(

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upsert the `big` table it has to be keyed and `upsert` operator should be used. For example

```
n:5000000
//big ids are unique numbers from 0 to 499999
//table is keyed with 1! operator
big:1!([]id:(neg n)?n;val:n?100)
//big ids are unique numbers. 250 from 0-4999999 and 250 from 500000-1000000 intervals
small:([]id:(-250?n),(n+-250?n);val:500?100)
```

If `big` is global variable it is efficient to upsert it as

```
`big upsert small
```

if `big` is local

```
big: big upsert small
```

As the result `big` will have 500250 elements, because there are 250 common keys (id column) in big and small tables

Answer (score 1):

this may not be relevant, but just a quick thought. If your big table has a column which has type `sym and if this column does not really show up that much throughout your program, why not cast it to string or other value? if you are doing this update process every single day then as the data gets packed in your partitioned hdb, whenever the new data is added, kdb+ process has to reassign/rewrite its sym file and i believe this is the part that actually takes a lot of time, not the union calculation itself..

if above is true, i'd suggest either rewriting your schema for the table which minimises # of rehashing(not sure if this is the right term though!) on your symfile. or, as the above person mentioned, try to assign attribute to your table.. this may reduce the time too.